# How to add new logics via Z3 or SMT-Lib?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, lib

I have a theoretical part, where I describe new logics and I want to implement it. But I don't want to do everything from scratch.

I see a big potential in SMT-Lib/Z3, so how can I implement my logics using these tools?

And after the implementation I intend to run several examples based on my logics.

Comment: Proofs/verification employing logics richer than what SMT-LIB supports are typically encoded into SMT-LIB. For example, Viper (http://viper.ethz.ch/) encodes proofs based on separation logic into SMT-LIB, which is a very involved process. This enables a tool stack, in which even "higher" tools encode proofs using even richer logics into Viper, and thus ultimately into SMT-LIB, as e.g. here: described https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-89960-2_11.

Answer (score 1):

- Axiomatize your logics in sorted first-order logic.
- Declare the logic sorts and symbols and add the axioms in SMT-LIB format.
- Use these commands as preambles to your examples.

Depending on your logics, you may also try to express them using pre-defined logics, such as Arrays, instead of plain first-order logic.